# What is a portable way to get the name of the current executable?

Tags: c++, boost

I want to extract the name of the current binary and use it inside my program. Can I do this somehow?

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  std::cout << arv[0]; // print name of program
  return 0;
}
```

Basically, I want a **portable** version of the above? I am happy to use any Boost or Standard Library tools.

Comment: there isn't one (although I don't know of a platform that doesn't usually work as you described). And this is a dupe. Lemme find it (

Comment: As it goes with the questions that you figure must have been asked by others, the linked answer was from 2009 and has 217 upvotes. Wasn't hard to find :/

Comment: @sehe that's disappointing. I'm surprised boost doesn't provide something. I think I didn't find the existing question because I didn't know what this was called...

Comment: Something like "Application Framework" or something seems to be in the making with Boost [https://github.com/retf/Boost.Application]. PoCo already has it. You could look at those.